# Swift - SKAction moveByX, How to get my node to move from the top/down

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

please forgive me as I'm a bit of a Swift noob and am creating my first game :D

Ok, so I have two nodes... one is Guava and the other is Pepper. Guava moves from the bottom of the screen to the top. I want the Pepper to move from the top of the screen to the bottom. Here's the code I have, which works fine for the Guava.

```
// movement of guavas
let guavaToMove = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 2.0  * guavaNodeTexture.size().width)
let moveGuava = SKAction.moveByX(-guavaToMove, y: self.frame.size.width, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * guavaToMove))
let removeGuava = SKAction.removeFromParent()

// movement of peppers
let pepperToMove = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 2.0  * pepperNodeTexture.size().width)
let movePepper = SKAction.moveByX(-pepperToMove, y: self.frame.size.width, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * pepperToMove))
let removePepper = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    GuavaMoveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([moveGuava,removeGuava])

    PepperMoveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([movePepper,removePepper])
```

Now I have the Guava Node anchored to the bottom of the screen and it floats up perfectly. I have the Pepper Node anchored to the top of the screen and am trying to get it to float down in a similar fashion.

Here is the code for both functions, spawnGuava and spawnPepper where both nodes/textures are anchored:

```
func spawnPepper(){

        //The way the Guava spawn and move

        let pepperNode = SKNode()

        let pepper = SKSpriteNode(texture: pepperNodeTexture)

        pepper.setScale(0.30)
        pepper.position = CGPointMake (self.size.width + 140, self.size.height * 0.75)
        pepper.alpha = 0.75
        pepper.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: pepper.size)
        pepper.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        pepper.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        pepper.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Guava
        pepper.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
        pepper.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Boognish

        pepper.zPosition = 50

        pepperNode.addChild(pepper)


        pepper.runAction(PepperMoveAndRemove)

        self.addChild(pepperNode)


        if scoreIncreased == true {


        }



        //the way the pepper collide

    }


    func spawnGuava(){

        //The way the Guava spawn and move

        let guavaNode = SKNode()

        let guava = SKSpriteNode(texture: guavaNodeTexture)

        guava.setScale(0.75)
        guava.position = CGPointMake (self.size.width - 40, self.size.height * 0.05)
        guava.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: guava.size)
        guava.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        guava.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        guava.alpha = 0.75
        guava.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Guava
        guava.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
        guava.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Boognish

        guava.zPosition = 0

        guavaNode.addChild(guava)


        guava.runAction(GuavaMoveAndRemove)

        self.addChild(guavaNode)


        if scoreIncreased == true {


        }



        //the way the guava collide

    }
```

Please help me configure this code accordingly so that the peppers fall from the sky :)

THANKS in advance. First post :)

FYI: I have tried modifying the code many times myself to no avail, so I have reverted it to the baseline you see now. IF I anchored the pepper to where the Guava is anchored then both would float up at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to move guavas and peppers in the opposite direction, but it seems like you are moving them in the same direction. Try removing or adding negative signs in `movePepper`:

```
let movePepper = SKAction.moveByX(-pepperToMove, y: -self.frame.size.width, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * pepperToMove))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have already tried that. After some research I believe the (-) sign in front of pepperToMove in the SKAction.moveByX is there to set some sort of point where the movement comes from, not necessarily where the movement is going. Also, adding a (+) does not have a reverse effect either..

I just tested it on the Guava node and the node completely disappeared after removing the (-)

Comment: What about the `y` value in `moveByX`? `let movePepper = SKAction.moveByX(-pepperToMove, y: -self.frame.size.width, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * pepperToMove))`

Comment: I figured it out in the simplest way, small tweaks :) see the answer above. Thanks for reaching out though :D

Comment: Nice! Just for future reference, dividing by -1 is the same as multiplying by -1.

Answer (score 0):

// movement of peppers
        let pepperToMove = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 2.0  * pepperNodeTexture.size().width)
        let movePepper = SKAction.moveByX(-pepperToMove, y: self.frame.size.height / -1, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * pepperToMove))
        let removePepper = SKAction.removeFromParent()

just has to divide the y value by a negative, derp... :D